# TCP socket stops writing in the midway of a loop

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have the following code and my write stopps writing to socket after a few hundreds of bytes sent. I've read bytes with fread using "rb" flag.

```
char filebuff[size_aux];
i=0;
int negative=0;
int positive=0;
int zero=0;
while( i<size_aux ) //size_aux is 79067
 {

  bytesSent = write(clnt_fd, &filebuff[i], 1 );
  if(bytesSent>0) positive++;
  if(bytesSent<0) negative++;
  if(bytesSent==0) zero++;

  i++;

}
```

What it printed was this:

```
Positive: 868
Negative: 78199
Zero: 0
```

I've checked that it sends 868 straight in a row and then stops sending, giving -1 as write turn value. The number of bytes sent is random, sometimes like 868 other times like 600, but small values compared to the real size of the file.
Before this, I had to insert the following code:

```
signal (SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Because in the middle of the while loop, it would exit my program to the terminal.

Comment: Is the socket non-blocking?

Comment: Read the documentation on write. Look at the error codes. Now fix your code to look at those error codes in detail, or at least print out what errors your code is getting.

Comment: The errno giving me is 0, so I can't do much. How do I know if a socket is non-blocking, I have no access to the server code.

Comment: Try checking sock_errno to see the error code.

Comment: What operating system are you doing this on? And did you include <errno.h> ?

Comment: I've finnaly got the correct error, and it says "Broken Pipe". I'm using debian.

Comment: @Elsendion If write returns negative, the write failed. It most likely fails because the other end closes the connection. You'll have to figure out why the server closes the connection.

Comment: Try reducing the 'size_aux' to near the MTU of your system to make each write call output a smaller payload. In general try not to exceed 64k per write call.

Comment: Ok, i'm contacting the administrators of the server regarding the non_blocking socket issue, and too see if they can send me some feedback. Will be back at you after I got response.

Comment: But if you look closer, i'm sending 1 byte at a time, the thing is I will run the loop thousands of times, but that doesn't interfere with the socket.

Comment: True, I stand corrected, missed that tiny 1 at the end :). Did you try larger packets?

Comment: Yes, i've try send 256 bytes at a time, and after like 5 or 6 times it writes, it stops.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a SIGPIPE signal, or an EPIPE error returned from write(), that means the reading end of the socket has stopped listening to you.

Your only response is to close the socket. You cannot make the other side receive more bytes and the connection is dead.